# Set a saved search as the default Finder window

Tags: finder

Does anyone know how to set a saved search as the default finder window when you press cmd + n in Finder?

When I go to Finder prefs - I am able to select the 'saved searches' folder from the 'New Finder Windows Show' drop down - however this only opens the enclosing folder for my saved search, not the actual particular saved search itself, in it's own window which is what I am after.

Thanks!